# How to tag the owner of the bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hi I'm making a bot that states the info of the bot, but I would like it to tag me as the owner.

```js
var owner = [ <@574798611552927745> ];
let argsS = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
if (argsS[1] === 'version') {
  message.channel.send('The **Mafia Bot** is currently at version: **' + version + '**!');
} else {
  message.channel.send(`**The Mafia Bot** was made by ${owner}`);
}
break;
```

Although I can't use the `<@` and there is no other way to tag me that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually tag a use writing that way **in a string**: `"<@574798611552927745>"`.
This is not a good way to do it though: every time someone uses that command you will be pinged (unless you disable mentions' notifications, but then you lose the real mentions) and, if you want the bot to be usable in other guilds, it'll show "invalid user" if seen by someone that is not connected to you.

The best way to do that would be to only show your `name#1234` tag or, if you really want to, to mention you only if you're in the guild.

```js
const owner = await client.fetchUser('user id here');

// Always show the tag
message.channel.send(owner.tag);

// Show the tag only if you're in the guild
let areYouInGuild = !!message.guild.member(owner);
message.channel.send(areYouInGuild ? owner : owner.tag);

// Always tag you
message.channel.send(owner);
```

Comment: i'm getting an error while testing with the await

```const owner = await client.fetchUser('575630348600475658');
              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function```

Comment: You have to put the code in an async function or use the `.then()` after `fetchUser()`. For more about async stuff and promises, check out [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: I'm using the exact code provided...
```async function f(){

                    const owner = await bot.fetchUser('575786632397979658');

                    // Always show the tag
                    message.channel.send(owner.tag);

                    // Show the tag only if you're in the guild
                    let areYouInGuild = !!message.guild.member(owner);
                    message.channel.send(areYouInGuild ? owner : owner.tag);

                    // Always tag you
                    message.channel.send(owner);
                
                }```

Comment: there is no error nor is a message actually sending

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: that is only an example that shows you three ways to "mention" you in a message. You have to include that code by yourself in the part that makes your embed: instead of sending `${owner` like you're currently doing you need to either send the owner user object or the `owner.tag`, like I showed you in my example.